# Hibernate Eager initialization fetches multiple instances of the parent object

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have following two entities

```
@Entity
public class Manufacturer {

    private int manufacturerId;
    private Category category;
    private Set<Products> productList;



    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="manufacturer_products", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="manufacturerId")}, 
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="productId")})
    public Set<Product> getProductList() {
        return productList;
    }
    public void setProductList(Set<Product> productList) {
        this.productList = productList;
    }
        @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="categoryId")
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}


@Entity
public class Product {

    private int productId;
    private String modelNumber;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Category category;
    }
```

I want to look up manufacturers related to a category. Since, the relationship between products and manufacturer is initialized eagerly it fetches me all the manufacturer instances mapped inside manufacturer_product table. Also, note the output list contains multiple instances of the same manufacturer. If I try to lazily initialize  then in that case it gives me a LazyInitialization Exception or I am required to loop through the product list and fetch the data manually. I am trying to avoid the later approach since, that would be a great performance hit. I have gone through the hibernate documentation but I couldn't find any solution to my problem. Please let me know if I am missing anything or if you need anything else. Any help would be highly appreciated.

This is my DAO class method to which I pass the Manufacturer instance with Category set in it. It does the look up based on that.

```
public List<Manufacturer> findByCategory(Category instance){
    log.debug("Get Manufacturer by Category");
    try {
        List<Manufacturer> results = (List<Manufacturer>) sessionFactory
                .getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria("com.me.ham.core.model.Manufacturer")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("category", instance))
                .list();
        log.debug("findByCategory successful, result size: "
                + results.size());
        return results;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("findByCategory failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the DAO method which I have used to do the look up

Comment: I guess you have more than 1 manufacture. Why not to change from OneToMany to ManyToMany relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HQL the soultion is something like this, if I understand correctly:

```
 select m 
 from Manufacturer m 
    left join fetch m.category cat
    left join fetch m.productList productList
 where cat = :categoryParam
```

I'm not an expert writing criterieas, but you can use `setFetchMode`. There are some information here: [Hibernate performance: 19.1.2](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot man...I made some minor tweaks with the query and changed the fetch type to Lazy and its working well. Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome. A regular rule you keep the model relations lazy and control the fetch mode within queryies.